# Why does this svelte code return different values randomly on refresh?

Tags: svelte

I am trying to measure the height of a svelte component. I wrapped it in an html element to do so. Sometimes the code works and returns `56`, which is what the inspector tool says is the height.

But other times it returns `25`, which is never referenced in the dev tools.

```
<script lang='ts'>

  import { onMount } from 'svelte';
  import DataTable, {
      Head,
      Row,
      Cell,
    } from '@smui/data-table';
  import { tick } from 'svelte';
  let headElement;
  let headHeight = 0;
  
  
  
    const measureHead = () => {
      if(headElement) {
        headHeight = headElement.offsetHeight;
      }
    }
    onMount(async () => {
      measureHead();
      await tick();
      console.log("Height: ", headElement.offsetHeight) 
    })
  
  </script>

  
  <DataTable table$aria-label="User list" style="width: 100%;" >
    
    <div bind:this={headElement}>
    <Head>
          <Row>
          <Cell style="width: 100%;">Title</Cell>
          <Cell>Type</Cell>
          <Cell numeric>Distance</Cell>
          </Row>
     </Head>
     </div>

  </DataTable>
```

Here's an image of the console after a refresh:

[image: strange svelte behavior]

edit: I thought it had something to do with the timing the component is rendered to the dom, hence `tick();`, but that does not work.

On every load following server start or a manual refresh the wrong value is returned. If I modify the file (and I mean any modification, even declaring some random variable `let foo = 0`) to trigger a hot update (I'm using vite), it returns the expected value of `56`.

I greatly appreciate an explanation of what is happening here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not reactive at all.  Instead, use Svelte's capabilities for measuring.  [Take the lesson here](https://learn.svelte.dev/tutorial/dimensions).

REPL Sample: [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/9eb658eb87b24758b3d06e1b76456b9b?version=4.2.8)

### Details

First, the code where measurement takes place:

```html
<script>
    import ToBeMeasured from './ToBeMeasured.svelte';

    let measuredHeight;
</script>

<h1>Ruler Example</h1>
<div class="container">
    <div class="ruler" bind:clientHeight={measuredHeight}></div>
    <ToBeMeasured />
</div>

<p>Measurement: {measuredHeight} px</p>

<style>
    div.container {
        position: relative;
    }
    div.ruler {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        pointer-events: none;
    }
</style>
```

We are using Svelte's built-in measurement feature by binding to the client height of our ruler div, but in order to be non-intrusive, we are using a floating invisible DIV, not the container DIV.  We make the container capable of being the anchor of absolutely-positioned elements by setting its position to `relative`, then we float the ruler DIV and set its height and width to 100%.  For your case, setting the height is enough as you only want to measure height.

Once this is done, the measurement is fully reactive.

### Would Measurement Work on the Container?

I would say Yes to this question.  I just believe in using a dedicated element to measure to separate responsibilities because most of the time, the container is not exclusively added for measurement and most of the time it serves other purpose(s).

Comment: Thank you. This was a super helpful explanation. I’m brand new to front end and only just beginning to make sense of the paradigms

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have to wrap it in an HTML element, & you also don't have to measure the offsetHeight yourself. Svelte has a way to get the offset height through `bind:offsetHeight={offsetHeight};`, & you can have this line inside your component: `export let offsetHeight;`. Then, to use the offsetHeight variable from the parent component, simply add this line to your Head component like so:

```
    <Head bind:offsetHeight>
    // your children elements here
 </Head>
```

and at the top of your parents script tag, add this line:

```
let offsetHeight;
```

Comment: Forgive me if this is a dumb question but is `export let offsetHeight;` how the component would pass the data back to its parent to use?

Comment: That's just a Svelte feature, I guess. It works for me, atleast. I had an InputWrapper component that applies some defaults to the input element, and wanted to grab a DOM refrence to that element, so inside the component I did export let inputElement: HTMLInputElement (typescript), and in my parent component, I just added the line bind:(variable), variable being the inputElement variable. It works for any variable that you declare inside the child component through export